# Input name array on symfony2

Tags: symfony, silex

I have a very long form and would like to group some fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name"profile[name]">
<input type="text" name"formation[school_name]">
```

I read about collections but I don't know to do this using collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll put some possibilities here as an answer.

If you just want to group your fields in the html then render each field on it's own in your twig template rather than rendering the entire form. You can read about that in the [Symfony2 Form Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template)

If you need to render many forms with each one having the `profile[name]` and `formation[school_name]` then you likely want to use form collections. For example create a form type called `Diego\MyBundle\Form\Type\MyNameAndSchoolType` to hold your `profile[name]` and `formation[school_name]`. In the form that you display,

```
$builder->add('myNameAndSchool', 'collection', array(
                    'type'          => new \Diego\MyBundle\Form\Type\MyNameAndSchoolType(),
                    'label'         => 'myBundle.nameAndSchool.label',
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'prototype'     => true,
                    'by_reference'  => false
            ))
```

You read about form collections but for completeness here is the link [Form Collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)
which also explains how to set up prototypes and some javascript examples for adding and removing records.

You may also want to check out [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) which has examples and helpers for handling collections including a javascript implementation.

I hope that helps a bit. I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to approach this as well.